# why is my multiplication function in haskell not letting me multiply a float?

Tags: function, haskell, multiplication

so this is my multiplication function:

```
multiplicacion n 1 = n
multiplicacion n m = n + (multiplicacion n (m - 1))
```

works with integers but when attempting to multiply floats:

```
*Main> multiplicacion  4.1 4
16.4
```

that works but if the second argument is also a float, this happens:

```
*Main> multiplicacion  4 4.1
```

the function breaks.

Comment: Please tell me how you expected it to work and why.

Comment: The computer is doing exactly what you told it to

Comment: Try to evaluate this yourself in your head, or on paper - you'll soon see the problem.

Comment: Beyond the problems described below, note that `Float` subtraction could introduce rounding errors, and that might make you miss the base case as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see what's happening, unroll the function execution - i.e. repeatedly replace function call with its body.

Let's consider the first example:

```
multiplication 4.1 4
= 4.1 + (multiplication 4.1 (4 - 1))
= 4.1 + (4.1 + (multiplicaiton 4.1 (3 - 1))
= 4.1 + (4.1 + (4.1 + (multiplicaiton 4.1 (2 - 1)))
= 4.1 + (4.1 + (4.1 + 4.1)
= 16.4
```

Now let's look at the second example:

```
multiplication 4 4.1
= 4 + (multiplication 4 (4.1 - 1))
= 4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (3.1 - 1)))
= 4 + (4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (2.1 - 1))))
= 4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (1.1 - 1)))))
= 4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (0.1 - 1)))))
= 4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (-0.9 - 1))))))
= 4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (-1.9 - 1)))))))
= 4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (multiplication 4 (-2.9 - 1))))))))
... and so on
```

The second argument will never be equal to one, and therefore the first definition `multiplication n 1 = n` will never match, and therefore the function will forever call itself.

Your function can only multiply by positive integer numbers. Giving it a fractional number results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're decrementing `m` by 1 every call. So let's look what happens with `mult 4 4.1`, expanding each line:

```
mult 4 4.1
4 + (mult 4 3.1)
4 + (4 + (mult 4 2.1))
4 + (4 + (4 + (mult 4 1.1)))
4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (mult 4 0.1)))))
4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (4 + (mult 4 (-0.9)))))))
...
```

based on this expansion, can you see what's going wrong here? Because at no stage does `m` actually *equal* `1`, you never hit the base case.